# PostgreSQL: number of rows inserted into table partitioned using 'ON INSERT ... DO INSTEAD' rules

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning

Looking into http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/rules-status.html, I'm under the impression that PostgreSQL will return the correct number of inserted rows if in addition to non-overlapping conditional rules you create an unconditional `ON INSERT ... DO INSTEAD NOTHING` rule.

If this is really true then why is such a useful statement not included in the PostgreSQL docs? (I could truly not see it being mentioned anywhere in the docs.)

Answer (score 2):

Rules expand an initial query into multiple queries. And the affected row count reported by psql or the apis, is that of the last query. If you use rules, you're essentially guaranteed that the reported number will be incorrect sooner or later -- no ifs or buts, it *will* come back and bite you.

Avoid rules, too, unless you know what you're doing. There are occasional discussions on pg hackers to deprecate them.

Comment: Thank you, especially, for the 'deprecate' hint. What about triggers?

Comment: _Occasional_ discussions. I find the immensely useful, easy to write and far more descriptive on trivial, flat updatable JOIN views than diving into the world of triggers. For Big Magic, triggers, sure, but then a need for Big Magic often is a symptom of deeper issues. Anyway, any do instead rule that isn't totally flat give you a wacky insert report number. With triggers you could declare a variable and increment it with each change -- but this begs the question why its so important in the first place...

Comment: @zxq9: a wacky reported number can screw up an `if found` statement in plpgsql.

Comment: @Denis This is true. If that is a requirement then I would consider the use case outside the realm of being simple enough for a rewrite rule. But that's no reason deprecate or be afraid of them.

Comment: I honestly have no idea why they're deprecating them precisely. You'd want to go through the pg-hackers list and the pg wiki for the gory details... e.g. http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Deprecating-RULES-td5727689.html

Comment: Denis, thanks for "gory details". Any advice about how to implement partitioning?

Comment: @SamMesh: it would be too long for a SO comment, but there's some discussion in the Postgres manual on this when it mentions table inheritance.

Comment: @Denis: I wanted to ask whether there are any recent changes in partitioning implementation area. It looks like partitioning part of PG manual wasn't changed for a long time.

Comment: @SamMesh: not that I'm aware of. Back when I was following it with some regularity, there used to be occasional threads on pg-hackers related to the way table inheritance works, but they always seemed to freeze along the lines of: we've had this legacy code for ages, so we can't change this.

Comment: if you have an unconditional rule you should get back its query return value, though, consistently, is that correct?